# Gtk3 is not not able to display window (using python 3.4 in windows 8.1)

Tags: python, gtk3

I am a beginner I am learning programming (Python basically) and in python there is something called GTk I have version 3 of it which help us to create gui applications so I started learning it and I try to create a simple blank window but the blank windows is not displaying its does not show any error it does not show anything I am using python 3.4 in window 8.1 I use sublime text 3 and here is my code:

```
import gi 
gi.require_version("Gtk","3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

win=Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```